# importing numpy for python 3.8.2

Tags: python, numpy

i just downloaded python 3.8.2 and i cant import numpy , 
i  get 
'''invalid syntax '''
no matter what i try for example i tried :

```
import numpy
```

here the output is

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

now for this code

```
python -m pip install --user numpy scipy matplotlib ipython jupyter pandas sympy nose
```

and

```
 sudo apt-get install python-numpy python-scipy python-matplotlib ipython ipython-notebook python-pandas python-sympy python-nose
```

and

```
sudo dnf install numpy scipy python-matplotlib ipython python-pandas sympy python-nose atlas-devel
```

i get

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

but no use .

Comment: Show us the full error output!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `sudo`, you seem to be using a UNIX-like operating system.

On those systems, the `python` command may or may not be available, and it may point to Python 2 or Python 3.

Since you get an "invalid syntax" error, I suspect that `python` is actually linked to `python2`.

If you have installed Python 3.8, the command `python3.8` should exist. Use that when trying to install `numpy` using `setup.py`.

For the same reason, do not call `pip <module>`, but use `python3.8 -m pip <module>` to ensure it is installed for Python3.8.

When using `apt-get` of `dnf`, I expect that you have to include the version number in the package names somehow. Check the repository that you're using.

Comment: non of this is working , i even tried other version like python 3.7.7 , and same output !

Answer (score 0):

problem solved 
it turns out that i should have custom installed python , and checked the option of 
'Add python to environment variables' 
now things run smoothly