# Difficulty with installing numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have tried to install `numpy` however I get an `invalid syntax` error.

This seems to be a common issue as I have searched across the web for a solution, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47632891/pip-install-returning-invalid-syntax)-[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61297086/importing-numpy-for-python-3-8-2)-and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548030/why-does-pip-install-inside-python-raise-a-syntaxerror)

I have tried all three and cannot seem to figure it out.
I'm a complete beginner to python, so this way of doing things are new to me. I have currently installed the latest python 3.9, is there something I may have missed?

Comment: Which command have you tried? When did this error occur, when importing `numpy`?

Comment: I have tried `pip install numpy` in python idle; although I have read that I have to install `numpy` on the cmd.exe, when I try this it cannot find `pip`. I have only recently started, so `numpy` is my second install, whereas `math` installed correctly, as my first install.

Comment: which os? can you check `python -V`

Comment: @Shijith It returns `namerror: name python is not defined`

Comment: `python -V` in cmd not in idle, also `where pip` , https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#configuring-python

Comment: When I try `python -V` the cmd returns nothing. however, when I enter `where pip` the cmd returns `could not find files for the given pattern(s).`

Comment: I have managed to fix this issue on my laptop. However, I now get the problem of `import numpy` failing to pass a sanity check.

Comment: I followed the link provided in the output from `import numpy` and installed the older version of it and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

go to tools, manage packages, search for numpy, find package from PyPl, install, make sure you type import numpy at the very start of the code